# Django testing json dump view

Tags: django, unit-testing, testing, django-testing

Hi I have a view like so:

```
def AjaxPopulate(request):
    colour = request.GET.get('colour_id')
    if colour is None:
        return HttpResponseBadRequest()

    qs = Thing.objects.select_related()
    things = get_list_or_404(qs, colour=colour)
    data = []
    for x in things:
        data.append({
            'id': x.id,
            'name': unicode(x),
        })
    return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(data), mimetype='application/json'
```

which is hooked into this url:

```
url(r'^ajax_populate/$', 'colours.views.AjaxPopulate', name='ajax_populate'),
```

in my test I have:

```
def setUp(self):
    self.client = Client()
    user = User.objects.create_superuser('foo', 'myemail@test.com', 'bar')
    colour1 = Colour.objects.create(colour='Green')
    thing1 = Thing.objects.create(name='Leaf', colour=colour1, description='foo')

def test_ajax_populate(self):
    response = self.client.get('/colours/ajax_populate/', {'colour_id': 1}) 
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

However, I am getting a `AssertionError: 404 != 200` error.

What am I doing wrong?

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: the url might be incorrect. use reverse instead (i.e. reverse('ajax_populate') ). don't hardcode urls. http://django.steerway.com/tip/bNk8P/do-not-hard-code-urls-use-name-in-url-patterns-then-use-reverse-in-your-views-url-tag-in-your-template-to-resolve-urls/

Comment: The URL certainly looks incorrect to me you have `ajax_populate/` at the root in your url conf and you're asking for `/colours/ajax_populate/` in the test. Are you including this urls.py from somewhere else? If so, you'll need to remove the `^` at the start of the url line.

Comment: +1 for http://django.steerway.com/! Though the problem boiled down to incorrect `setUp ()`, the url should definitely not be hardcoded, so thankyou for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Final code which worked.

**tests.py**:

```
class ViewTests(TestCase):
    """
    Run before each test in class
    """
    def setUp(self):
        self.client = Client()
        self.user = User.objects.create_superuser(
            'foo',
            'myemail@test.com',
            'pass'
        )
        self.colour = Colour.objects.create(colour='Green')
        self.thing = Thing.objects.create(
            name='Leaf',
            colour=self.colour,
            description='leafy'
        )
        self.logged_in = self.client.login(
            username='foo',
            password='pass'
        )

    """
    Test ajax call
    """
    def test_ajax_populate(self):
        response = self.client.get(tests.py
            reverse('ajax_populate'),
            {'colour_id': self.colour.pk})
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```